# Apex:charts - Changing the appearance of apex:axis titles

Tags: charts, visualforce-charting

I've been exploring the use of the apex:chart tag functionality recently (see below a bar chart of favorite pie fillings). I am now at the point where I want to modify the appearance of the chart.

I am more than happy with using the apex:chartLabel tag to alter the appearance/styling of axis value labels (see rotation below), but is there any way to change the appearance/styling of the axis titles? Ideally I would like these to be smaller, but I can't see any tag level option to do this, am I missing something?

[image]

Chart markup:

```
<apex:chart height="250" width="100%" data="{!pieData}" >
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Fillings">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data" steps="1" minimum="0" title="count"/>
    <apex:barSeries xfield="name" yfield="data" orientation="vertical" axis="bottom" colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
</apex:chart>
```

Comment: This gets my upvote purely because of the quality of the diagram! :D

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no standard way of changing the styling of the titles of `apex:axis` components. Using `apex:chartLabel` only changes the formatting of the labels themselves (the text or numbers) rather than the axis titles.

You can however use `SfdcApp.Visualforce.chart.VFChartMgrInst.afterMethod()` and a bit of jQuery to change the styles of the `apex:axis` titles after the chart has been loaded, it may be possible to improve the selectors I've used, but these should work for your example.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    SfdcApp.Visualforce.chart.VFChartMgrInst.afterMethod('load', function()
    {
        var xAxis = $j( "text[text='{!multipicklistFieldName}'][id^='vfext4-ext-sprite-']");
        xAxis.attr('font', 'bold 5px Arial');
        xAxis.css('font', 'bold 5px Arial');

        var yAxis = $j( "text[text='count'][id^='vfext4-ext-sprite-']");
        yAxis.attr('font', 'italic 20px Arial');
        yAxis.css('font', 'italic 20px Arial');
    });
</script>
```

It should be noted that using `afterMethod` and calling `SfdcApp.Visualforce.chart.VFChartMgrInst` directly is as far as I'm aware undocumented, and therefore unsupported. Visualforce Charting is still in it's infancy as a feature, so until there is a documented way to do this it's probably the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Attacking the SVG elements themselves with CSS works alright:

```
<style>
    text {
        fill: white !important;
    }
</style>
```

[image: graph]

Comment: `!important` tag as noted is vital otherwise the CSS selector doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the font/color properties on the `<apex:chartLabel>` component. It changes the font of whatever component wraps it.

Comment: PS: That chart just made me realise I'm hungry :P

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and comment :D ) Rohan, I've tried applying the apex:chartlabel at all levels on my example above, but still I can't seem to affect the size of those axis labels :S

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I was wrong. It seems you can't change the axis label, only the internal labels within the graph. You should probably vote for the idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Ji9gAAC

Answer (score 0):

Copied from documentation:
You can use `<apex:chartLabel>` in this way:

```
<apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name"
        title="Month of the Year">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="315" font="Helvetica" field="{!chartLabel}" color="#FF0000"/>
</apex:axis>
```

Reference: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartLabel.htm

Comment: Hi Regal, thanks for the suggestion, but there is no such apex:title tag, and the title attribute only controls the label applied to the axis.